# Create xmlns using tinyxml

Tags: c++, xml-namespaces, tinyxml

I am new to tinyxml, I would like to generate the following xml file using tinyxml library. Could you please help me out with this
many thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>    
    <geo:Sim xmlns:geo="http://www.xxx/geo"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.xxx/geo file:/geoX.xsd">
 <GG>
 </GG>
</geo:Sim>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TinyXML does not know or care about namespaces. However, that doesn't mean you can't use them. You just have to write namespace declarations like they were regular attributes. So if you want to define the `geo` namespace, make an attribute named `xmlns:geo` and give it the value of the namespace. And so forth.

Similarly, the element will have to be named `geo:Sim`.

Comment: This gives only partial support for XML namespaces.  XML namespaces should be inherited by child elements unless the child explicitly overrides its namespace.  Also, there won't be support for namespace prefixes, so a declaration of `xmlns:foo="http://www.foo/1.0"` won't allow for child elements such as `<foo:bar>this element is in the http://www.foo/1.0 namespace</foo:bar>`